# Small C program makes 500+ mallocs?

Tags: c, macos, malloc, valgrind

I have been learning C for a while and I am writing C code for a project. I mainly tried to test the usage of structs. I wrote a simple create and delete method for it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TokenizerT_ {
  int index;
};

typedef struct TokenizerT_ TokenizerT;

TokenizerT *TKCreate( char * ts ) {
  TokenizerT *tk = (TokenizerT *)(malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT)));

  if(tk == NULL)
    return NULL;

  tk->index = 0;

  return tk;
}

void TKDestroy( TokenizerT * tk ) {
  free(tk);
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    TokenizerT *tk = TKCreate(argv[1]);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(tk->index));
    TKDestroy(tk);
    return 0;
}
```

So, this compiles and prints 4 as expected on my machine. However, when I ran it through valgrind I get this:

```
==816== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==816== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==816== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==816== Command: ./test
==816== 
--816-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./test"
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
4
==816== 
==816== HEAP SUMMARY:
==816==     in use at exit: 38,504 bytes in 415 blocks
==816==   total heap usage: 516 allocs, 101 frees, 45,484 bytes allocated
==816== 
==816== LEAK SUMMARY:
==816==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==         suppressed: 38,504 bytes in 415 blocks
==816== 
==816== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==816== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I don't know if this is helpful but my machine is OSX 10.10.5. I really have no idea how my program makes 501 mallocs.

Comment: If I recall, Valgrind has some trouble with the latest versions of OS X.  Try running your program on a Linux machine or VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your code; it is the startup code that is leaking.  The crucial information for you is:

```
==816== LEAK SUMMARY:
==816==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==816==         suppressed: 38,504 bytes in 415 blocks
```

Especially the last line.  I'm using a version of Valgrind with the same version number but almost certainly considerably older, and I had to add a whole pile of suppressions.  Someone else seems to have done it for you.

So, don't worry about it — it is normal on Mac OS X to have a pile of 'in use' or 'suppressed' memory.

When I run this mildly hacked version of your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TokenizerT_ {
  int index;
};

typedef struct TokenizerT_ TokenizerT;

TokenizerT *TKCreate( char * ts );
TokenizerT *TKCreate( char * ts ) {
  TokenizerT *tk = (TokenizerT *)(malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT)));

  if(tk == NULL)
    return NULL;

  tk->index = strlen(ts);

  return tk;
}

void TKDestroy( TokenizerT * tk );
void TKDestroy( TokenizerT * tk ) {
  free(tk);
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    TokenizerT *tk = TKCreate(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "CogentConniptions");
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(tk->index));
    TKDestroy(tk);
    return 0;
}
```

The hacks were necessary to avoid compilation warnings under my default compilation options:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror vg.c -o vg
$
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ valgrind vg
==31534== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31534== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31534== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31534== Command: vg
==31534== 
--31534-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--31534-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--31534-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
4
==31534== 
==31534== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31534==     in use at exit: 38,874 bytes in 418 blocks
==31534==   total heap usage: 519 allocs, 101 frees, 45,854 bytes allocated
==31534== 
==31534== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31534==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==31534==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31534==      possibly lost: 13,002 bytes in 109 blocks
==31534==    still reachable: 25,856 bytes in 308 blocks
==31534==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31534== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==31534== 
==31534== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31534== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

And with my hand-crafted `suppressions` file:

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=suppressions vg
==31538== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31538== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31538== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31538== Command: vg
==31538== 
--31538-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--31538-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--31538-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
4
==31538== 
==31538== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31538==     in use at exit: 38,874 bytes in 418 blocks
==31538==   total heap usage: 519 allocs, 101 frees, 45,854 bytes allocated
==31538== 
==31538== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31538==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31538==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31538==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31538==    still reachable: 25,856 bytes in 308 blocks
==31538==         suppressed: 13,018 bytes in 110 blocks
==31538== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==31538== 
==31538== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31538== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

The suppressions file you have built-in does a better job than mine does.

Comment: So all I should care about are the first 4 rows of leak summary? Is there any way I could fix this problem?

Comment: If you mean 'fix the suppressed leaks', you could join Apple's Mac OS X team and resolve the problems by fixing their run-time.  However, it probably isn't worth doing that; the program is about to exit by the time the leaks are leaks.  So basically, just keep an eye on the 'definitely lost', 'indirectly lost' and 'possibly lost' values, and try to make sure that the 'still reachable' and 'suppressed' are about 38± KiB.  If you see those numbers dramatically bigger, then there's something wrong.  Use the `--leak-check=full` option, and maybe even avoid the built-in suppressions.

Comment: And yes, I find it scary that Mac OS X is doing so much work before running a program.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ran it on a Linux VM and it had no leaks at all.

Comment: You're welcome.  It scared me when I first ran my 'new' (in November 2014) copy of Valgrind.  I understand your concern.  The suppression-file related options to Valgrind are: `--default-suppressions=yes|no`
_load default suppressions [yes]_,
    `--suppressions=<filename>` _suppress errors described in filename_, and
  `--gen-suppressions=no|yes|all`   _print suppressions for errors? [no]_.  I used `--gen-suppressions` quite a lot.  Review `valgrind --help` and the manuals for more information on the subject.